# Pass variables from PHP to text file from button press

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've tried AJAX, but I cannot seem to get this working. I've scoured stack, and the internet. So thanks in advance if someone can help me.

What I have is formatted JSON. I'm able to use `json_decode` to pump out an associative array. I'm able to then iterate through that array and display want I want and store them in variables. I have a button and id like when clicked to use AJAX to call PHP file to write those variables to a text file.

I tried using

```
function dothis() {
    $.get("/abc.php");
    return false;
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="dothis();">Click Me</a>
```

If I run `abc.php` manually, it functions as expected but `onclick` appears to do nothing. Can someone point me in the right direction, or show me a better example of AJAX. I appreciate it.

edit: 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
dothis 
onclick

is what is displaying in console

Comment: The path to the PHP script would be the URL to the file, not the file system path.

Comment: thanks, that was the last edit i made, i was grasping at straws.  i originally had "/abc.php". now its throwing Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in console.

Comment: It looks like you're using jQuery. Mention that in your post and put a link to the the relevant docs (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get).

Comment: Are you trying to send the "variables" over ajax? If so i see no mention of them in your code.

Comment: Might pay to write your jQuery properly, i.e. put your function declaration inside `$(document).ready()` and remove the onclick handler on the element in favour of a class e.g. "myclass" then assign a click handler in your document ready block e.g. `$('.myclass').click(dothis);`

Comment: Are you definitely including the required jQuery script, could that be why you're getting the TypeError?

Comment: Max yes its in my frame work head, im sorry if my code is wrong i got the code from stackoverflow as an accepted answer with 44 upvotes.  i will look into jquery proper code, honestly ive never used javascript, jquery a little with databases.  so this is new territory.  im sorry it seems ive angered some just for asking a question.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly more complete AJAX GET request using [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). It uses the idea mentioned by +scrowler in the comments above.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function dothis() {
        $.get('/echo/json/').done(function(data, textStatus) {
            console.log("AJAX request complete: " + textStatus);
        }).fail(function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Do some error reporting in here, but for now...
            console.log("AJAX request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
    }

    // This is the bit that scrowler is talking about
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ajax-button").click(dothis);
    });
</script>
<a href="#ajax" class="ajax-button">Click me!</a>
```

Here it is on jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h79oLc1r/

Comment: using your code still produced the same error, but i was able to figure it out.  my lack of experience made me question what i had.  in reality the problem was another library holding the $.  i was able to fix it.  thank you for your help, and your code helped me greatly.